# Compare two emails in two text fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form which lets the user to enter the email address twice. i need to validate that the email is like the regex and that the two emails match.

Something is wrong with my code. Please note that i am restricted to use javascript only. Thanks,
this is my javascript

```
function checkEmail(theForm) {

    var re = /^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+"[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/i;

    if (theForm.EMAIL_1.value != re) {
        alert('invalid email address');
        return false;
    } else if (theForm.EMAIL_1.value != theForm.EMAIL_2.value) {
        alert('Those emails don\'t match!');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"something is wrong with my code."* What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Also, that is one funky looking email regex.  I have great doubts it would match any valid email address.  You can search the web for a solid email regex rather than home brew it.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue your not actually performing a regex. Your just comparing a regex string to an email.

```
if(theForm.EMAIL_1.value != re) /// <--- wrong. 
{ 
    alert('invalid email address');
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- On errors, use [`Event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the form submit
- Check for ***email validity*** only on the first input value
- Than check to ***string equality*** on both input fields

```js
function checkEmail (event) {
  const e1 = this.EMAIL_1.value;
  const e2 = this.EMAIL_2.value;
  //Email Regex from //stackoverflow.com/a/46181/383904
  const re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  const isEmail = re.test( e1 );
  const isMatch = e1 === e2;
  if( !isEmail ){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Invalid email address');
  }
  else if ( !isMatch ){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Those emails don't match!");
  }
}

document.querySelector("#theForm").addEventListener("submit", formSubmitHandler);
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
  Email address:<br>
  <input name="EMAIL_1" type="text"><br>
  Confirm Email address:<br>
  <input name="EMAIL_2" type="text"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Since you might have more forms where an email is required (Contact form, Login form, Newsletter form, etc etc...) for more **modularity** you could create a reusable function for validation and than a specific form submit handler separately:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} a Email address 1
 * @param {string} b Email address 2
 * @return {string} Error message
 */
function invalidEmails (a, b) {

  a = a.trim();
  b = b.trim();
  if (!a || !b) return "Missing email"; 
  
  // Email Regex from stackoverflow.com/a/46181/383904
  const re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  const isEmail = re.test(a);
  const isMatch = a === b;
  
  if      (!isEmail) return "Invalid email";
  else if (!isMatch) return "Emails do not match";
}


// Handle your form here
function formSubmitHandler (evt) {
  const is_emails_invalid = invalidEmails(this.EMAIL_1.value, this.EMAIL_2.value);
  if (is_emails_invalid) {
    evt.preventDefault();      // Prevent form submit
    alert(is_emails_invalid);  // Show error message
  }
}

document.querySelector("#theForm").addEventListener("submit", formSubmitHandler);
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
  Email address:<br>
  <input name="EMAIL_1" type="text"><br>
  Confirm Email address:<br>
  <input name="EMAIL_2" type="text"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the code but i am finding a bit of a difficulty. it cannot work with my code. i am adding the 'onsubmit="return checkEmail(this);"' in the form and it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You cant compare the first value with a regex. You have to use a regexp object. For more information read at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: w3schools is not a reliable page (never was), and I think it was built by mistake. They even sell fake diplomas, they're not related to W3C by any means and the site is not maintained by an active and critical community of programmers. (Edited your link to a better resource)

Comment: All right I will use mozilla reference from now on. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below function to validate your email.
And after the validation, compare the 2nd email.

Please note that regex ***test*** method is used in the validateEmail method.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work perfectly!

```
function validateForm(theForm) {

    if (theForm.Email_1.value != theForm.Email_2.value)
    {
        alert('Emails don\'t match!');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```